# Waitable Timer, Running Every Interval?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, timer

Using C#, .NET Framework 4.0.
I have 3 TimeSpan objects set to 20 minute, 30 minutes, 45 minutes. I want to have a Timer execute only at the exact minute intervals, regardless of when any timer actually starts. 
I need to have timer firing look like this (every hour):

```
timerA 1:00
timerB 1:00
timerA 1:20
timerB 1:30
timerA 1:40
timerC 1:45
timerA 2:00
timerB 2:00
timerA 2:20
timerB 2:30
timerA 2:40
timerC 2:45
```

I thought a Waitable timer would be the right move, but with the lack of simple examples out there, I guess not. What is the best way to get this functionality (I would like to avoid clock drift if possible but I'm desperate for anything right now)? I am not married to Waitable. I also understand that timerC is only going to run once an hour, which is fine since it is set to only run at the 45th minute of every hour.

Note -  I am not ready to use Quartz.NET.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @Snowy, what programming language are you using? .NET? Furthermore, in your example timer C executes every hour, not every 45 minutes... is that what you actually wanted?

Comment: Use only one timer so they'll never drift apart.  Set it to the next due interval then sort out what needs to be done.  Always calculate the interval from the clock, never add an increment because that will always drift late.

Comment: @Hans, I'm not sure if he really needs them to be that precise, it seems that he wants minute precision (seems like the he implied it he said the exact minute interval).

Comment: You might be interested in Waitable Timers in C#: http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Waitable-Timers-in-NET-CSharp/. Code is available at http://www.mischel.com/pubs/waitabletimer.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the work for you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20.0), "TimerA", true);
    StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30.0), "TimerB", true);
    StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45.0), "TimerC", true);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The start timer function starts the timer and returns it (if you need the reference). The key here is that you give it the timer name and you tell it if you want to align the timer to the full hour. If you don't want to align to the full hour, then the timer will be started immediately with the specified frequency.

```
public static Timer StartTimer(TimeSpan frequency, string timerName, bool alignToHour)
{
    if (alignToHour)
    {
        return new Timer(OnTimerTick, timerName, ComputeDelay(frequency), frequency);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Timer(OnTimerTick, timerName, TimeSpan.Zero, frequency);
    }
}
```

The function that will be fired when the timer ticks.

```
public static void OnTimerTick(object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)state + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm"));
}
```

This method computes the delay that would be required if the timer has to be aligned on the full hour. It only works if the frequency is less than one hour or more than one minute.

```
public static TimeSpan ComputeDelay(TimeSpan frequency)
{
    if (frequency > TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0) || 
        frequency < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "The frequency cannot be more than one hour or less than one minute!");
    }

    return frequency - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(DateTime.Now.Minute % frequency.Minutes);
}
```

**NOTE:** in your example you run the 45 minute timer on a 1 hour frequency, yet you run the 20 and 30 minute timers on 20 and 30 minute frequencies (respectively). My code doesn't work with a 45 minute timer on a 1 hour frequency, but it does work with 20, 30 and 45 minute timers on their respective frequency. I'm not sure if your example is wrong or not, but if it's not wrong then I think you should be able to figure out how to take care of that difference from here on.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get is to 'creep up' on the target-time, using a waitable, (sleep(), event with timeout, some threaded timer or classic 'main thread windows timer), set to half the number of milliseconds between 'now' and the target time, as calcuated from the real-time clock.  If the remaining ms is greater than some limit, (say 500), recalcualate the ms remaining and wait again. When the remaining ms is lower than the limit, start looping round the real-time clock until the target is reached or exceeded, then call the timeout() method of your TimeSpan object.

You could put your TimeSpan objects in a timeout-time ordered queue so that you only need one waitable.  This may be more accurate if you have cases where the TimeSpan events often happen 'simultaneously' since there is only one thread looping as the target time is neared.

Rgds,
Martin